# I've set Content type to 'application/json', but I have 403 error

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, http

I am doing app and it contains two part, backend - spring, frontend - js.
My post request. (js):

```
function addUserToDB() {

    origin='*';

    let user = {
        "telephone": "+375296534488",
        "name": "Potemin",
        "password": ["p", "a", "s"],
        "passwordRetry": ["p", "a", "s"],
        "address": {
            "city": "New York",
            "street": "State",
            "houseNumber": 22
        }
    };

    $.post('http://localhost:8080/registration', user, data => {console.log(data)})
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <script src="js/registration.js"></script>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"
            integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="addUserToDB()" id="b">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring:

```
package com.project.sushipizzabar.users.controllers;

import com.project.sushipizzabar.users.UserService;
import com.project.sushipizzabar.users.dto.userDto.UserCreateRequest;
import com.project.sushipizzabar.users.dto.userDto.UserDto;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Arrays;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/registration")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private final UserService service;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> addUser(@RequestBody UserCreateRequest userCreateRequest) {
        if (!Arrays.equals(userCreateRequest.getPassword(), userCreateRequest.getPasswordRetry())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.findById(service.create(userCreateRequest)));
    }


}
```

It's working by postman, but spring returns this:

```
2023-07-20T16:44:33.363+03:00  WARN 5328 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
and js: POST http://localhost:8080/registration net::ERR_ABORTED 415
```

I added securityConfig, but now I have 403, I think its because spring security does not allow and therefore I have anther problem. I dont know how to disable spring security in new version, where WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is not exist.

config:

```
package com.project.sushipizzabar.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .anonymous(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("ttp://localhost:63342/").permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:63342/"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/registration")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:63342/")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }

}
```

I tried to change headers, but nothing happened. I did get method without headers and body, nothing changed.
All user's variables are right. I read another issues about this, but i found only about content type.

Comment: You are trying to send a `Content-Type:application/json` header, but the server is receiving `Content-Type:text/plain`. You need to figure out where in transit the header is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach would still work if you just use `$.ajax` instead to explicitly set the contentType. Because you're making the call from a browser the default `content-type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; char

```
  function addUserToDB() {
            origin='*';
    
        let user = {
            "telephone": "+375296534488",
            "name": "Potemin",
            "password": ["p", "a", "s"],
            "passwordRetry": ["p", "a", "s"],
            "address": {
                "city": "New York",
                "street": "State",
                "houseNumber": 22
            }
        };
    
        $.ajax({
           url: 'http://localhost:8080/registration',
           type: "POST",
           data: user,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: dataType
        }).done(console.log)
   }
```